# Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, typescript

All rows from the CSV file are converted to JSON objects that are added to the resulting array, which is then converted to JSON, and a corresponding JSON output file is generated.

I get TS error:

```
 TypeScript error: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. TS2538
```

```js
        /* Empty object to store result in key value pair */
        const jsonObject = {};
        /* Store the current array element */
        const currentArrayString = row;
        let string = "";

        let quoteFlag = 0;
        for (let character of currentArrayString) {
          if (character === '"' && quoteFlag === 0) {
            quoteFlag = 1;
          } else if (character === '"' && quoteFlag == 1) quoteFlag = 0;
          if (character === ", " && quoteFlag === 0) character = "|";
          if (character !== '"') string += character;
        }

        let jsonProperties = string.split("|");

        for (let j in headers ) {
          if (jsonProperties[j]!.includes(", ")) {
            if (headers[j] !== undefined && !headers[j]) {
              jsonObject[headers[j]] = jsonProperties[j]!.split(", ").map(
                (item) => item.trim()
              );
            } else jsonObject[headers[j]] = jsonProperties[j];
          }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration/initialization of the `headers` variable?

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems like you might have undefined properties in headers, therefore `headers` values can not be used as index type. Has to be filtered.
2. Seems like the actual value in the list is used as an index type here `headers[j]`.

While iterating over headers, the `j` is already the needed value.

```
const filteredHeaders = headers.filter(x => x !== undefined);
for (let j in filteredHeaders ) {
    if (jsonProperties[j]) {
      if (jsonProperties[j].includes(", ")) {
         jsonObject[j] = jsonProperties[j].split(", ").map(
            (item) => item.trim()
         );
      } else {
         jsonObject[j] = jsonProperties[j];
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Header is defined const property